# Insert table button in bootstrap-wysiwyg

Tags: bootstrap-wysiwyg

I have an HTML editor based on [bootstrap-wysiwyg](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg) on which I'd like to add a *Insert table* button. According to what stated in [issue #17](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/issues/17) it should be possible to do this using an *insertHtml* call.
So I tried adding a row like this:

```
<a class="btn" data-edit="insertHTML" value="<table><tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td></tr></table>"><i class="icon-table"></i></a>
```

but doesn't work...

Comment: How is it not working?  What is it doing that it's not supposed to, or vice versa?  Any sort of errors or anything that can help to debug?

Comment: Nothing happens, no error in firebug, nothing at all :(

Comment: Grasping at straws, does changing the case to `data-edit="insertHtml"` help at all?

Comment: sadly not, it's apparently case insensitive as other commands I have use capitals randomly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried much, but finally found the solution to this:

```
<a class="btn" data-edit="insertHTML <table><tr><td>Val1</td><td>Val2</td></tr></table>" ><i class="icon-table"></i></a>
```

Hope it fits for you.

Comment: indeed it works, thanks! 
not really the result I expected, but not certainly your fault ;) thanks again!